# Listview inside listview Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

I want to create listview inside listview. I tried below code, which is not working in Android, same code working perfectly in iOS

```
<local:CustomListview
          x:Name="ListView"
      ItemsSource="{Binding List1}" HasUnevenRows="True"
          >
          <local:CustomListview.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout
                Orientation="Vertical">
                  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding CreatedOn}"></Label>
                  </StackLayout>
                  <Label Text="{Binding Description}"></Label>

                  <StackLayout
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    >
                    <Label Text="{Binding Count}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="Likes(s)"></Label>
                  </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout
                      Orientation="Vertical"
                      Padding="5, 0, 0, 0"
                    >
                        <local:CustomListview ItemsSource="{Binding List2}" HasUnevenRows="True">
                         <local:CustomListview.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                  <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                      <Label Text="{Binding Description}"></Label>
                                      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding CreatedBy}"></Label>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding CreatedOn}"></Label>
                                      </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                  </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                         </local:CustomListview.ItemTemplate>
                      </local:CustomListview>
                    </StackLayout>      

                </StackLayout>
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </local:CustomListview.ItemTemplate>


        </local:CustomListview>
```

Any suggestions?

I can't use group listview, since I need to arrange controls like Label in particular way. I am binding child listview as part of parent listview's ItemsSource. Above code is not working, its showing only parent listview, child listview is not displayed.

Comment: Why is it "not working" on Android? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 4):

Listview inside a Listview is not a supported option. Listviews are designed to be the only root control on a page, mainly due to sizing and scrolling concerns.

Also the complexity of the page might cause poor performance.

Ideally I would suggest reworking your layout so that the repeated information is on another page. However if you want to continue on with this approach you should look at the [RepeaterView](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/RepeaterView) in XLabs. Its basically an enhanced StackLayout.

Comment: "Listviews are designed to be the only root control on a page" is wrong, even if I agree with the general idea of your answer. As a generalization, avoid nested scrolling control in any mobile application.

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix - how is it exactly wrong? That was its intention if I remember a comment from Jason Smith and a separate one from Craig Dunn correctly. Due to its need to scroll and size to the page, it is best if its only the root element. While I certainly have had multiple listviews on a page which does work, Jason mentioned its not really supported as it can run into many issues. Unless that sentiment has changed in recent updates?

Comment: I think when you say only root control. this sounds like if there is listview on a page you have to put everything inside listview which is not correct. what you mean by repeated information on another page? Do you mean to use like contentview?

Comment: What I am trying to convey saying a listview was (possibly originally) designed to be the first control on the page. Anything outside of the ItemTemplate should be put in the header or footer template and nothing outside of the listview. This was certainly preferable as the ListView wants to take the full height of the screen, then allows scrolling within it. Otherwise you have to scroll down to then scroll through the listview, hence 2 types of scrolling occurring at once, which may cause issues. As I mentioned it can certainly be done but can cause issues.