# Xamarin Forms - Implementing a nested list

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I have a list of details (Basket) and in each of those details, is another list (Fruits). I want to display these details and the very first thing I thought of, was a ListView inside a ListView. But when looking through suggestions, gave me results such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35223540/7196681) and [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/horizontal-list-view-inside-list-view-in-xamarin-android/) which mostly suggests that it is not a good idea to implement in Xamarin Forms.

At the moment, I'm using FreshMvvM as my MvvM Framework. As for the data that I want to display, I have a set of baskets and each basket has several fruits. I want the images of those fruits to be displayed as well, which belongs to a particular basket. Please refer the image.

[image]

I would like to know if there are improvements to this or else, any other ideas of layouts as to how to implement my list or any other way to implement the above behaviour. Thank you.

My code so far:
**XAML:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Baskets}" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding BasketID}" />
                    <ImageCell 
                        Text="{Binding FruitID}" 
                        Detail="{Binding FruitName}" 
                        ImageSource="{Binding ImageURL}">
                    </ImageCell>
                </StackLayout>
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Classes:

```
public class Basket
{
    public string BasketID{ get; set; }
    public string BasketName{ get; set; }
}

public class Fruit
{
    public string FruitID{ get; set; }
    public string FruitName{ get; set; }
    public string ImageURL{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You might have to implement a custom renderer, since the way it is implemented in XF, nested lists will crash on Android at least.

Comment: @PaulKertscher yes I would like to have the app with as less crashes as possible. If you can, please show me some guidelines/links that would help me to create the custom renderer. Thank you.

Comment: Please see https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/ - there is many information about custom renderers. Unfortunately I cannot help you that much beyond this, since I gave up using nested `ListView`s and solved my issue in another way.

Comment: Thank you for the info @PaulKertscher. Also, if I may ask, other than using nested ListViews, what are the other possible ways to implement the above behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ListView` to iterate through baskets collection, while using a custom control like [`ItemsControl`](https://github.com/xamarinhq/xamu-infrastructure/blob/master/src/XamU.Infrastructure/Controls/ItemsControl.cs) to iterate through fruits collection.

It basically is a custom control that allows you to add dynamic children support to a `StackLayout` through `ItemsSource` and `ItemTemplate` properties. You can use the control as it is - except you will need to set the `Orientation` property to `Horizontal` on its StackLayout at this [line](https://github.com/xamarinhq/xamu-infrastructure/blob/master/src/XamU.Infrastructure/Controls/ItemsControl.cs#L112).

**Sample Usage:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Baskets}" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding BasketID}" />

                    <local:ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}">
                        <local:ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </local:ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </local:ItemsControl>
                </StackLayout>
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

> Note: `ItemsControl` is good for usage with only small collections, as the virtualization/recycling support is not very sophisticated. I am assuming, as the layout is horizontal, number of items in `Fruits` collection will be relatively a low.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I will try this and check.

Comment: Can you please explain what I should be referring using `local`? Sorry for the dumb question

Comment: So I am assuming - you have already downloaded and added the `ItemsControl` class to your project. Now, you have to declare the namespace you used - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces/#Declaring_Namespaces_for_Types

Comment: Thank you. It worked. However, I would like to know whether I can replace `<Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" />` with other elements. For example, another `StackLayout` or a `TextCell` and an `ImageCell`, because using those elements does not show anything in the app

Comment: Yes - you can replace it with any element that you can add to a StackLayout

Comment: @SharadaGururaj ImageURL Binding is not working in Android, but same code working fine in UWP