# Xamarin forms listview Inside listview crash only in Android

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my case, I am adding a listview inside another listview, the binding of data takes place without any issues but when i try to scroll the list items, I am getting this exception

```
Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter from native handle 0xbf82c28c (key_handle 0x29208f0e).
```

And inner exception shows

```
{System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) ---> Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
      at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateProxy (System.Type type, System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00054] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
      at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateInstance (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type targetType) [0x00111] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 }
```

Im using Xamarin 3.3.0 and Android version 7.1

I want some workaround for this. How to fix it?

Comment: Take a look at this answer from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235111/10256655

Comment: already i saw that, iOS its working fine only android getting this Exception and in Xamarin android iistview inside listview its possible only forms its crashing.@NetoCosta

Comment: Just don't use it like that :D ... Instead try using RepeaterView there is very nice implementation by our great community member Glenn Versweyveld you can find it here: http://depblog.weblogs.us/2017/09/24/xamarin-forms-repeaterview/.